# What is causing a "Maximum function nesting level" error in Symfony 2.1 and Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a project on Symfony 2.1. After updating composer components (Gedemo, Symfony core, Doctrine, Twig, etc..) I have the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/{path}/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Token.php on line 78
```

I have PHP 5.4. What can cause this error?

Comment: Probably you have too many loops somewhere in your views. You should analyze your code, check and refactor logic. Good start could be to analyze the trace of functions in that error

Comment: @thecatontheflat, actually, it can happen under normal conditions when rendering forms in Twig in the dev env.

Comment: If you'd like to expand your answer a bit, I'll be happy to restore it and reopen this question.

Comment: As much as I like the question, none of the given answers actually give hints on where to look to reduce the nesting level of Twig or how to debug it. Increasing the nesting level doesn't solve the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Find the `xdebug.ini` file:

```
$ locate xdebug.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

In my case the file is `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`. Open it and add this line:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

Don't forget to restart the FPM server.

Comment: whats an FPM server.  Do you just need to restart apache?

Comment: @Robbo_UK, if you're using Apache and mod_php, then yes, restart the Apache server. [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org) is the modern way of running PHP.

Comment: had the same error trying to run codeception tests with Laravel 5 and this fixed it

Comment: Sorry to look like a stickler, but can you also answer the `What is causing` part of the question? I'd be interested if you could explain. Thanks!

Comment: @BartaTamás : Check your templates inheritance since this is related to twig. What can cause the problem is overwriting a template in your bundle and extending the parent bundle template at the same time.

Comment: This isn't answering the question properly, merely hiding the problem of a bad loop running somewhere in the site.

Answer (score 2):

it is an error code that causes an infinite loop, but it happens from time to time that treatment without error exceeds the 100 calls nested functions.

To correct this, open the php.ini, xdebug section and add the following line (putting what you want instead of 150)

```
 [xdebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 150
```

Comment: Setting a very large number like 10000 isn't advised, as it may freeze your computer. If you can't fix your problems with 1000, then it's highly probable that your script has a problem.

Comment: i agree with Shehi that for example Function A calls Function B and Function B calls Function A - this will cause an infinite nested loop, this is logical error that you will need to figure out using trace/breaks in debug mode or removing chunks of code to quickly find out issue. Try removing the code you just added in just before this issue happens and you will see.

Comment: but  the symfony form  generate number of loop
which will generate an error of this type
in  windows I have increased this value to correct the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing a little tips to new Twig developers who might be interested to understand the "What is causing.." part of the question.

Obvisouly in the original question the max nesting level is rather low (100) and as some comments mention, it might be too low for normal circumstances.

However, if one increases the level to, say 256, 512 or even 1000 as adviced above and still hit the same error, then perhaps the most potential thing to look at would be [the template inheritance](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html). (The `extends` keywords on the first line of the templates)

This is especially the case with projects where you have templates in multiple locations.

Imagine an example project structure:

```
── plugins
   ├── your-plugin
   |   ├── views
   |   │   ├── base.twig
   │   │   ├── special-element.twig
   │   │   ├── some-other-element.twig
── theme
   ├── base.twig
   ├── index.twig
   ├── sub-page.twig
```

The *plugin* has a template `base.twig` which extends the `base.twig` under the *theme*. But if the template locations are not correctly configured, the templates might end up extending itself again and again causing the infinite loop.

How to check if this is the case? I'd be happy to hear about more accurate solutions, but one can start - for debugging purposes only - as simple as referring to the parent templates with the full server paths:

`{% extends "/var/www/path-to-your-template/" %}`

If it starts to work with absolute paths, then you can be quite sure there is something wrong with the template paths. Read more about it here: [Twig Template Naming and Locations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-naming-locations)

Answer (score 0):

if increasing `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000` failed check namespace is correct

eg: `namespace App\Entities;` but folder name in lower case `app`

then entity should contain namespace as `namespace app\Entities;`

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I had to increase the amount of memory used by PHP in **php.ini** to 512MB. Also, I made a **composer update** on the site root folder to update the default settings generated by Symfony.