# getting error maximum function nesting level of 200 reached

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently working on `Symfony`, `Rest API`. I am new to this `framework`. I have installed `Symfony` correctly. and now I have installed `FriendsOfSymfony` bundle, every thing is going fine but when I am clicking on `logout` then I am getting following error

```
 Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 6010
```

After some searching I found a solution to set `xdebug` in `php.ini`, to set set limit 200 instead of 100, then I am getting the following Error,

```
 Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 6010
```

Totally I am unable to see a demo of symfony also. Please guys tell me how Can I come out of this problem ?

Comment: There is some infinite loop somewhere of course, check your code about possible recursions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.1, Twig errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213378/symfony-2-1-twig-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check the call stack. Maybe you have an ifinite loop.
Deactivate xDebug or set the maximum nesting level in the php.ini higher:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

This is a normal behavior.
try something like:

```
    $traceStack = debug_backtrace();
    var_dump($traceStack);
    $i=0;
    foreach($traceStack as $n) {
        /* do what you want here */
        /*
         *   $n is an array of:
         *   'file' => ..
         *   'line' => ...
         *   'function' ...
         *   'class' => ...
         *   'object' => ...
         *   'type' => ...
         *   'args' => ...
         */
    }
```

**Important**: Don't forget to restart apache (or FPM)!

Comment: when I am deactivating xDebug then I am getting error of 100 levels and i have set the level upto 500 also, I am getting the same error

Comment: I am new to symfony, and I am getting this problem only in demo page `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/` at this url, please can u help me how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to composer. Some vendors were updated in the **composer.json** file, but I forgot to run the commands **composer update** nor **composer install**. The system generated a cascade of errros, which was causing this 'maximum nested level'.

After executing those commands, the problem was fixed