# Symfony2: Times out w/ JMS Serializer nested object

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Attempting to serialize an object with 3 nested object properties results in

> Error: Maximum function nesting level of '250' reached

Entity Volunteer has OneToOne with Person, OnetoMany with Focuses, and OneToMany with Skills.  If the response is serialized `$volunteer->getPerson();` the expected json response occurs.  However, `$volunteer->getFocuses();` also triggers the maximum nesting level error.

#### Update

When xdebug max is increased, this just times out in 30 sec in dev environment.

#### Controller snippet:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$volunteer = $em->getRepository('HOTV2Bundle:Volunteer')->find($id);
$response = new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($volunteer, 'json'));
```

Comment: If this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308047/getting-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-200-reached

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid:  Thanks, but I'm not seeing how xdebug would affect the serializer.

Comment: i guess this is because you have enabled xdebug ,if this is the case try increasing the limit in php.ini

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Ah, the symptom, not the disease.  By either raising the max or deleting xdebug references entirely from php.ini, the script times out at 30 seconds in dev.  So now I see how xdebug affects performance, but the original problem of serializing an object with nested objects remains unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your maximum nesting level issue is an indication that you are trying to serialize much more than you need.

Specify the fields you want serialized with JMS entity configuration (annotations, xml, or yml). I use annotations. I always start by annotating my entity/document with @[ExclusionPolicy](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#exclusionpolicy)("all") and then explicitly @[Expose](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#expose) properties and relations.

The @[Accessor](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) and @[VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) method annotations are very useful for customizing your output. Instead of serializing related Focuses as objects, you could instead annotate a `getFocusTitles` method with @VirtualProperty to serialize a simple array of titles if this is all you need.

Of course you will need to annotate related entities as above.

Comment: Your contribution is appreciated and may come in handy - it has been rewarded.  I've since done a major redesign and no longer attempt to serialize that entity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a xdebug error message. This means that you have recursive functions that call themselves more than 250 times.

You should increase the nesting level in your php.ini.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

otherwise you can set the nesting level in your script with

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks. Even with a greatly extended xdebug nesting level it appears the serializer doesn't appreciate all the relationships in my model, which is why it times out.  I've since built a function to build an array that mimics the structure I'm looking for.  The array is then perfectly serialized.

Comment: What is when you disable xdebug in your php.ini is it then running? And are you shure that the nesting level is really over 250?

Comment: Quoting my friendly neighborhood `phpinfo();`  `xdebug.max_nesting_level 1000`

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that there was infinite recursion trying to serialize the entity I built the following array that could be serialized.  The function takes a Volunteer object as its parameter.

```
public function createVolunteerArray($vol) {
    $p = $vol->getPerson();
    $person = array(
        'id' => $p->getId(),
        'firstName' => $p->getFirstName(),
        'lastName' => $p->getLastName(),
        'email' => $p->getEmail(),
        'address' => $p->getAddress(),
        'city' => $p->getCity(),
        'state' => $p->getState(),
        'zip' => $p->getZip(),
    );
    $f = $vol->getFocuses();
    $focusArray = array();
    foreach ($f as $foc) {
        $focus['id'] = $foc->getId();
        $focus['focus'] = $foc->getFocus();
        $focusArray[] = $focus;
    }
    $s = $vol->getSkills();
    $skillArray = array();
    foreach ($s as $sk) {
        $skill['id'] = $sk->getId();
        $skill['skill'] = $sk->getSkill();
        $skillArray[] = $skill;
    }
    $volunteer = array(
        'person' => $person,
        'focuses' => $focusArray,
        'skills' => $skillArray,
    );
    return $volunteer;
}
```