# Symfony2 twig render makes a phpunit error

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

I can run a lot of phpunit tests with no problem,
but since i added a render() function in a column, phpunits seems to make a loop.
When i browse the website via browser, nothing is wrong. It is only on phpunit.

the twig render function:

```
{#located in /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/src/Tykayn/MeluzineBundle/Resources/views/Front/aside.html.twig#}
{% render( controller('TykaynMeluzineBundle:Default:aside') ) %}
```

the asideAction from the DefaultController renders this template:

```
TykaynMeluzineBundle:Widgets:aside.html.twig
```

i tried with a very simple test in my DefaultControllerTest.php:

```
$client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

what i get in command line is:

> PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/phpunit.xml.dist
>
> ..PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php on line
>   140 PHP Stack trace: ...

followed by 99 lines of stack trace, and dumping the html:

> PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0 PHP   2.
>   PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46 PHP   3.
>   PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129 PHP   4.
>   PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176 PHP   5.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349 PHP   6.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705 PHP   7.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745 PHP   8.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775 PHP   9.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:783 PHP  10.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648 PHP  11.
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:838 PHP  12.
>   ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983 PHP  13.
>   Tykayn\MeluzineBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest->testPanelZinesLink()
>   /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983 PHP  14.
>   Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/src/Tykayn/MeluzineBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:49
>   PHP  15. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:327
>   PHP  16. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:111
>   PHP  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
>   PHP  18.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2337 PHP  19.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3087 PHP  20.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2938 PHP  21.
>   call_user_func_array:{/media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976}()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976 PHP  22.
>   Tykayn\MeluzineBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976 PHP  23.
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/src/Tykayn/MeluzineBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:64
>   PHP  24.
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\DelegatingEngine->renderResponse()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php:107
>   PHP  25. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/DelegatingEngine.php:57
>   PHP  26. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php:99
>   PHP  27. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Debug/TimedTwigEngine.php:50
>   PHP  28. Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php:74
>   PHP  29. Twig_Template->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:50
>   PHP  30. Twig_Template->display()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:264
>   PHP  31. Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:253
>   PHP  32.
>   __TwigTemplate_9277ea238773dd29dfb2aa91841e0a11a6c6f6bc8a1cdb8d860ce584ad2f3026->doDisplay()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:279
>   PHP  33. Twig_Template->displayBlock()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/cache/test/twig/92/77/ea238773dd29dfb2aa91841e0a11a6c6f6bc8a1cdb8d860ce584ad2f3026.php:112
>   PHP  34.
>   __TwigTemplate_9277ea238773dd29dfb2aa91841e0a11a6c6f6bc8a1cdb8d860ce584ad2f3026->block_aside()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:144
>   PHP  35. Twig_Template->display()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/cache/test/twig/92/77/ea238773dd29dfb2aa91841e0a11a6c6f6bc8a1cdb8d860ce584ad2f3026.php:280
>   PHP  36. Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:253
>   PHP  37.
>   __TwigTemplate_b07be62a3c83f4e7ebe7ff20acb7d7a2056b50b1c96af248c686165d5b3272b6->doDisplay()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:279
>   PHP  38. Twig_Template->displayBlock()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/cache/test/twig/b0/7b/e62a3c83f4e7ebe7ff20acb7d7a2056b50b1c96af248c686165d5b3272b6.php:23
>   PHP  39.
>   __TwigTemplate_b07be62a3c83f4e7ebe7ff20acb7d7a2056b50b1c96af248c686165d5b3272b6->block_aside()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:144
>   PHP  40.
>   Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Extension\ActionsExtension->renderUri()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/cache/test/twig/b0/7b/e62a3c83f4e7ebe7ff20acb7d7a2056b50b1c96af248c686165d5b3272b6.php:40
>   PHP  41.
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\ActionsHelper->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Extension/ActionsExtension.php:48
>   PHP  42.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Helper/ActionsHelper.php:52
>   PHP  43.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\InlineFragmentRenderer->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/FragmentHandler.php:116
>   PHP  44.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php:85
>   PHP  45. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3087 PHP  46.
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2938 PHP  47.
>   call_user_func_array:{/media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976}()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976 PHP  48.
>   Tykayn\MeluzineBundle\Controller\DefaultController->asideAction()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2976 PHP  49.
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/src/Tykayn/MeluzineBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:37
>   PHP  50.
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\DelegatingEngine->renderResponse()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php:107
>   PHP  51. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/DelegatingEngine.php:57
>   PHP  52. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php:99
>   PHP  53. Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Debug/TimedTwigEngine.php:50
>   PHP  54. Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php:74
>   PHP  55. Twig_Template->render()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:50
>   PHP  56. Twig_Template->display()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:264
>   PHP  57. Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:253
>   PHP  58.
>   __TwigTemplate_2020b0148cc27066f88c28b44bacb973fae7400c61b1231c7375112ec14cd7a2->doDisplay()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:279
>   PHP  59. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/app/cache/test/twig/20/20/b0148cc27066f88c28b44bacb973fae7400c61b1231c7375112ec14cd7a2.php:31
>   PHP  60. Twig_Environment->compileSource()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:334
>   PHP  61. Twig_Environment->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:559
>   PHP  62. Twig_Compiler->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:543
>   PHP  63. Twig_Node_Module->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:86 PHP
>   64. Twig_Node_Module->compileTemplate() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Module.php:38
>   PHP  65. Twig_Node_Module->compileDisplayBody()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Module.php:61
>   PHP  66. Twig_Compiler->subcompile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Module.php:109
>   PHP  67. Twig_Node->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   68. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   69. Twig_Node_If->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   70. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/If.php:49 PHP 
>   71. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   72. Twig_Node_For->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   73. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/For.php:89 PHP
>   74. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   75. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   76. Twig_Node_If->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   77. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/If.php:49 PHP 
>   78. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   79. Twig_Node_Set->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   80. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Set.php:94 PHP
>   81. Twig_Node->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   82. Twig_Node_Expression_Binary->compile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php:105 PHP 
>   83. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Binary.php:28
>   PHP  84. Twig_Node_Expression_Binary->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   85. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Binary.php:28
>   PHP  86. Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   87. Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter.php:34
>   PHP  88. Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Call.php:30
>   PHP  89. Twig_Compiler->subcompile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Call.php:70
>   PHP  90. Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   91. Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter.php:34
>   PHP  92. Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Call.php:30
>   PHP  93. Twig_Compiler->subcompile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Call.php:70
>   PHP  94. Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   95. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/GetAttr.php:31
>   PHP  96. Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   97. Twig_Compiler->subcompile() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/GetAttr.php:31
>   PHP  98. Twig_Node_Expression_Name->compile()
>   /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Compiler.php:97 PHP
>   99. Twig_Node->getAttribute() /media/sdd2/www/meluzine/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Name.php:27

Comment: [Try increasing your `max_nesting_level`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13213409/1188035)

Comment: You're welcome. I've marked this as a possible duplicate of [What is causing a "Maximum function nesting level" error in Symfony 2.1 and Twig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213378/what-is-causing-a-maximum-function-nesting-level-error-in-symfony-2-1-and-twig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is `PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

Solve this problem by increasing the value of `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in your php.ini file