# Symfony2 Sonata Admin IvoryCKEditor wrong render for some reason

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin

I am trying to implement [IvoryCKEditor](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle) Bundle to my SonataAdmin entities and I am witnessing some very strange errors/bugs/mistakes... I dont even know..

So when I want to render a simple textarea field and add some longtext to it I simply do something like this:

```
    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
//            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('contentEn', 'ckeditor', array(
                'attr' => array('cols' => '8', 'rows' => '8')))
            ->add('contentEs', 'ckeditor', array(
                'attr' => array('cols' => '8', 'rows' => '8')))
            ->add('status')
        ;
    }
```

This works like a charm.. However if I have mapped entities and I want to show its fields I use sonata collection:

```
->add('translations', 'sonata_type_collection',
                    array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'label' => false,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'standard',
                    )
                )
```

And in the mapped entities admin I do this again:

```
$formMapper
            ->with('Item Info')
                //->add('id')
                ->add('product_name')
                ->add('description_for_lbi', 'ckeditor')
                ->add('short_description', 'ckeditor')
                ->add('long_description', 'ckeditor')
                ->add('conditions', 'ckeditor')
                ->add('language', null, array('required' => true))
            ->end()
        ;
```

Now here is the problem. Its seems the ckeditor form the collection is rendering in a completely different way.

The first example renders an iframe and makes the ckeditor look "clean".

In the collection ckeditor is rendering in a completely different way, no iframes.. And for the editor to show up I have to click on the field first.. And the field has no borders... I really dont know how to explain this.

So I guess my question is, why the ckeditor is rendering completely different when I am using it in a collection. Am I doing something wrong?

If you guys dont understand what I mean I can post some screens...

**UPDATE**

I thing the problem is here:

```
           'edit' => 'inline',
           'inline' => 'standard',
```

this makes the editor look bad. However if I remove these lines I get error:

```
Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

This error is when I am trying to edit an object

Comment: You're completely right in your Edit, however you can always use 'edit' => 'inline' if you create your own instance of ckeditor as described here: https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#load-manually-the-library

Comment: In order to fix the nesting error (which is recommended to do in the first place, I will post an answer now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely right with your edit. inline editing in ckeditor breaks if you have 2 or more instances of the ckeditor config.
My suggestion is to drop inline editing.

For the second part, the error comes from xdebug, which cannot follow your object nesting level because it exceeds this limit.
In order to fix this (which is recommended, as limit = 100 is way too low for symfony2), please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213378/what-is-causing-a-maximum-function-nesting-level-error-in-symfony-2-1-and-twig)
article.

Comment: okay, any javascript errors in your console (of any kind, not only regarding ckeditor)?