# Symfony 4.1 - Service using EntityManagerInterface produces max nest level error

Tags: autowired, entitymanager, symfony4

I have created a simple service that takes 4 parameters. When adding `EntityManagerInterface` as parameter I get max nest level error. The same happens even if pass the arguments manually (withought autowiring).

Interestingly enough when I remove the EntityManagerInterface parameter it all works fine. The problem is, I need the EntityManager in the service.

Any ideas where to look at?

Comment: You should update your xdebug.ini file like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213409/6045900

Comment: It's not xdebug related

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering in the future from similar situation the problem was the following

The service that was requesting for `EntityManager` was getting injected in a `doctrine lifecycle` class. Apparently this causes an infinite recursion issue as doctrine is not really initialised at that point and it tries to initialise it.

Setting the service as `lazy` doesn't work as it's required in the constructor. Is there some way around it to keep the EntityManager dependency in the service and still use it in the doctrine lifecycle event class?